# For loop - Array, indexOf(), concat()

Tags: loops, for-loop, concatenation, indexof

I'm working on this problem from FreeCodeCamp in JS.
Basically I need to find the difference between two arrays and then return an array with those values i.e. strings and integers.

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  //console.log(arr1.length);
  var newArr = [];
  var dummy = [];
    for (var x=0;x<arr1.length;x++) {
      if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[x]) === -1) {
        newArr = newArr.concat(arr1.slice(x));}}
    for (var y=0;y<arr2.length;y++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[y]) === -1 && newArr.indexOf(arr2[y]) === -1) {
        newArr = newArr.concat(arr2.slice(y));
      } 
    }
  console.log(newArr);
  return newArr;
}

diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

It almost works. Except these do not work:

- `[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` - Gives `[4, 5]`.
- `["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite",
  "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]` - Gives `["pink wool",
  "dead shrub"]`.

These work though:

- `[1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [1, "calf", 3, 4]`
- `[], ["snuffleupagus", "cookie monster", "elmo"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using slice and concat to feed your output array ?

- iterate through arr1
- if arr1 has an element which is not in arr2 push it to newArr
- iterate though arr2
- if arr2 has an element which is not in arr1 push it to newArr
- return newArr

Comment: Yeah, i dont really know. Guess i thought push only was for strings. I changed it and it worked. Thanks.